# Assertion for valid comes once in req-ack transaction

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, formal-verification, system-verilog-assertions

[image]

I want to write an assertion, which checks that "Valid should be high only once in req 1, ack 1, req 0, ack 0 transaction"

I thought of the following one, but it gives me error.

```
assert property (@(posedge clk_r) req & ~ack |-> (valid [=1]) throughout ((req & ~ack) ##[1:$] (~req & ~ack)));
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You should explicitly mention what a `req-ack` transaction means. The picture is a poor substitute for a description, especially without any context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by "error" you mean a compile error. The left hand side of a `throughout` operator can only be a boolean, not a sequence. You're thinking of the `intersect` operator.

`intersect` will require the sequences on its left and right sides to have the same number of cycles.

The sequence on the left side of the `intersect` should specify that there is one and only one cycle where `valid` is `1`. The non-consecutive repetition operator is a good start, because it says that `valid` can come in any cycle starting from the time the consequent match starts. It doesn't say what happens after that; it just says that there could exists subsequent cycles, but puts no requirements on those cycles.

You need to specify what happens after the cycle where `valid` is `1`, In order to ensure that there is a single cycle where `valid` is `1`, we have to check that `valid` is `0` for the cycles after that. This is done using the following sequence:

```
!valid [*] ##1 valid ##1 !valid[*]
```

This could be written in a couple of different ways, but I find the code above to be the most readable.

In the other part of the consequent, you can safely drop the `(req && !ack)` term and just say:

```
##[1:$] (!req && !ack)
```

It also doesn't do what I think you want it to do (check that `req` stays `1` until `ack` comes). You should have a different assertion that checks that `req` should stay `1`. This will make it easier to debug, because you split checks for `valid` from checks for `req` and `ack`.

Putting it all together, the assertion should look like:

```
assert property (@(posedge clk_r)
    req & ~ack |->
        (!valid [*] ##1 valid ##1 !valid [*]) within (##[1:$] (!req && !ack));
```

---

Note: you should use boolean operators, instead of bit-wise logic operators. Instead of `&`, use `&&` and instead of `~` use `!`.

Comment: The last one `untill_with`  I am getting confused. Can you share the meaning of last one? Also is `not` operator different from `~`?

Comment: I tried this one too - `req & ~ack |-> (valid) within (##[1:$] (~req & ~ack));`. But it didn't fail for 0 valid in the transaction. For 0 valid transaction, the assertion does not get completed. So we need something same, but an assertion which gets failed when req 0, ack 0 and valid has not become 1

Comment: For the valid "only once" case, I guess the following assertion works - 
`assert property (@(posedge clk_r) valid |=> ~valid[*1:$] ##1 ~req & ~ack);`

Comment: `not` is similar to the boolean `!` operator (I'd suggest using that instead of bitwise negation `~`), but it applies to properties.

Comment: I'm confused why the `within` assertion doesn't fail for the no `valid` case. The consequent should stop matching once both `req` and `ack` go low.

Comment: Your third comment inspired me and I think it's possible to write a single assertion.

Comment: Yes even I assumed that `within` should fail when req 0, ack 0 happens. I am not sure if that is tool specific issue or not. Now `valid only once` case can be checked with my new assertion then `valid not 0` may be checked with - `assert property (@(posedge clk_r) req & ~ack |-> valid [->1] ##[1:$] ~req & ~ack )`

Comment: I re-wrote the answer, since I think that people who read it won't care about the initial versions. They will care about how the final code should look like, so they can implement a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
property p1;
    @(posedge clk) $rose(req) |-> !ack ##0 $rose(valid)[->1] ##1 !valid ##0 ($stable(valid) throughout (##[0:$] ##1 ack[*] ##1 !req&!ack));  
endproperty
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32352117)